# how to add onclick event to radiobutton in java

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces

I am creaiting dynamically two radio buttons ( HtmlSelectOneRadio yes/no) and one input text box.

```
    HtmlPanelGrid optionGrid = //....
    optionGrid.getChildren().add(radios);  // adding yes and no radios
    optionGrid.getChildren().add(textbox); // adding input text box 
    questionGrid.getChildren().add(optionGrid);
```

I want to add a `onclick` event to make the input box disabled when user click no radio button. How can I add an event to this component which is created on the java side?

I want something like that:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="radio" checked id="id1" onclick = "return clickHandler();" value="a">Yes</td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="idTb" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="radio" id="id2" onclick = "return clickHandler();" value="b">no</td>
</td>
</tr>

function clickhandler(){
    //if radio button yes clicked then enable text box
    //else disable text box
}
```

Comment: I just editede my question. the reason why I am creating using Java is that structure has been created on that way previously therefore I do not want to break the structure.

Comment: Just do it like you would normally add an eventhandler to html from javascript

Comment: Just call `setOnclick` on the controls, passing the script text as the argument